# Proper implementation of a model class in php

Tags: php, mysql, oop, model

Hi I'd like to ask if my implementation of a model class is at least correct to OOP style.
I declare it as an abstract so that it can only be used on extending the 
class

sample code :

```
<?php
/**
 * class model handles dbconfig and some common query transaction
 * i declare it as an abstract so that it can only be used on extending the 
 *class
 */
abstract class Model
{
    //db config
    protected $sHost     = "localhost";
    protected $sUser     = "root";
    protected $sPass     = " ";
    protected $sDb       = "test";
    protected $sEngine = "MySQL";  
    protected $conn ;

    //constructor
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->sHost, $this->sUser, $this->sPass , $this->sDb);

    }   


    protected function db_query_list($sSql){

        if ($resultset = $this->conn->query($sSql)) {
            if ($resultset->num_rows > 0) {
                $data = array();
                while( $row = $resultset->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    $data[] = array_change_key_case($row);
                }
            }else {
            $data = false;
            }
        } else {
            $data = false;
        }

        $resultset->close();
        return $data;

    }

    protected function execute_query($SQL) {

        $run = $this->conn->query($this->sEngine);

        return $run;
    }

}
```

Then on implementation i extend model in CustomerModel

```
<?php

require "Model.php";

class CustomerModel extends Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getAllCustomer()
    {
        $sSql = "SELECT *
                 FROM t_classification_header
                 ";


        return $this->db_query_list($sSql);
    }

}
```

Notice that i use **parent::__construct();**.
I'm new in OOP any help would be my pleasure 
Any comments and suggestions are welcome . 
Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rather belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sad to see a comment like that

Comment: If you are looking for good OOP architecture, I'd recommend looking at Symfony. If you need a class, which works with your database, I'd recommend using dependency injection, instead of forcing to extend the class itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Create separated class, maybe even singleton, for actually interaction with DB and **pass it as argument of model constructor**. Why? If you work with 5 customers than your code will create 5 connections to DB. (Dependency Injection / composition)

2) Don't do `return $this->db_query_list($sSql);`. Wrap results into some `CustomersList` and/or wrap each row into `Customer`.

3) I would create class `Customers($DB)` with methods `all()`, `byId($id)`, etc. instead of `CustomerModel`. Seriously, we're not a photo agency and do not work with models. Yes, the class is a data model, but why bother with this code? For us, this is a concrete `Customer`, with specific data and behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the insight bro